# Why is my navigationlink not working. I get this error : "Result of 'NavigationLink<Label, Destination>' initializer is unused"

Tags: xcode, swiftui

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView
    {
        ScrollView
        {
            LazyVGrid(columns: [
                        GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 100, maximum: 200), spacing: 16, alignment: .top),
                        GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 100, maximum: 200), spacing: 16, alignment: .top)], alignment: .leading, spacing: 16, content: {
                            
                            ForEach(vm.results , id: \.self) { result in
                                PartyInfo(result: result).onTapGesture {
                                    NavigationLink(
                                        destination: SelectedPlaylistView(),
                                        label: {
                                            Text("")
                                        })
                                    
                                }//.padding(.horizontal)
                                //.background(Color.black)
                            }
                            
                
                        }).padding(.horizontal, 20)
                        
                
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because it is inside the `.onTapGesture` it is going into the `Void` of the closure.

Replace

```
 Text("")
```

With this

```
 PartyInfo(result: result)
```

Remove the `onTapGesture{}` the `NavigationLink` has it built in.

It will give you the result you seem to trying to achieve.

Comment: it fixes the error but when I tap the cells in the scroll view it doesn't navigate to the new view. Also, it changed my item layout from a double item layout per row to a single column of items in the scrollview

Comment: It should. There has to be something else going on that you aren't showing. Each `PartyInfo` should take you to `SelectedPlaylistView` per the provided code

Comment: `ForEach(vm.results , id: \.self) { result in
                                    PartyInfo(result: result)
                                    NavigationLink(
                                        destination: SelectedPlaylistView(),
                                        label: {
                                            
                                        })//.padding(.horizontal)
                                    //.background(Color.black)
                                }`.                        This is the new code but its not working. This is all i changed.

Comment: Your label is empty there is nothing to click on. Put the PartyInfo in the label closure where the Text was. You need to Replace the Text with the PartyInfo.

Comment: That worked thank you. that seemed such a small fix but I just couldn't figure it out.

Comment: I’m glad it worked. Do you mind accepting the answer? And maybe upvoting?